# Why isn't $\frac{d}{dx}(x^{sinx})$ simply $\frac{d}{du}(x^{u})*\frac{d}{dx}(sinx)$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, chain-rule

I know that this solution is wrong. The correct one is $\frac{d}{dx}(x^{\sin x}) = x^{\sin x - 1} (\sin x + x \log x \cos x)$, however I can't catch why there is a sum as result of the chain rule. I've seen this derivation with a log and an exponential trick but I'm not convinced yet. I didn't find any direct derivation without these two tricks. It would be of great help if someone did that here.

Comment: You have to replace the $x$ with what it is in terms of $u$ in the $\frac{d}{du}\left(x^u\right)$ part. Let $y=x^{\sin x}$. If $u=\sin x$, then $x = \sin^{-1}u$ (assume $-\frac{\pi}{2}\le x\le \frac{\pi}{2}$ for now), so $y = \left(\sin^{-1}u\right)^u$. So you would have $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy}{du}\frac{du}{dx} = \frac{d}{du}\left(\left(\sin^{-1}u\right)^u\right)\frac{d}{dx}(\sin x)$$ (which is no easier to compute). It's best to just write $y = e^{(\sin x)(\ln x)}$ and go from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are applying your chain rule, you are forgetting to differentiate the $x$ term in $x^{(\cdots)}$.

Your derivative is easier to calculate if you set $x = e^{\ln(x)}$. In this case, you have:
$$x^{\sin(x)} = e^{\ln(x)\sin(x)}$$
and the derivative is simply:
$$\frac{d}{dx}x^{\sin(x)} = e^{\ln(x)\sin(x)}\bigg{[}\frac{1}{x}\sin(x)+\ln(x)\cos(x)\bigg{]} = x^{\sin(x)-1}\bigg{[}\sin(x)+x\ln(x)\cos(x)\bigg{]}$$

Comment: Should't be $f(x) = [arcsin(x)]^{x}$ instead of $f(x) = x^{x}$?

Comment: Yes, I wrote it and then realized the dummy mistake. Sorry hehe

Comment: I corrected it even before than you post this comment.

Answer (score 1):

The trouble with differentiating things like $f(x)^{g(x)}$ is that neither of the rules for handling things like $f(x)^c$ or $c^{f(x)}$ will apply. Neither the base or the exponents are constants, this is a uniquely different situation. The 'trick' for these things are to use logarithms and implicit differentiation.  What we do to handle this situation is the following:
\begin{align*} 
y &= f(x)^{g(x)} \implies \ln (y) = f(x)\ln g(x) \implies y'/y = f'(x) \ln(g(x)) + f(x) \frac{g'(x)}{g(x)}\\ 
y' &= yf'(x) \ln(g(x)) + yf(x) \frac{g'(x)}{g(x)} = f(x)^{g(x)}f'(x) \ln(g(x)) + f(x)^{g(x)}f(x) \frac{g'(x)}{g(x)}  \end{align*}

Replacing $f$ and $g$ with $\sin(x)$ and $x$ will give you the result you would expect.

Answer (score 0):

$x$ is a function of $u$ so the first factor has to be 
$$\frac d{du}\left((\arcsin u)^u\right)$$